# Vuetify v-drawer keep open on large screen

Tags: vuetify.js, drawer

Is it possible to have Vuetify v-drawer open on large screen and open/close by the toolbar button on mobile screens?

Something like:
https://design.gitlab.com/brand/basics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70931919-gbrmr?file=/src/App.vue

[image]

This is a basic navigation drawer setup I made. Feel free to modify it to your needs and let me know if you need help with that!

Comment: This is close but not what i need:
1. When on big screen the drawer start closed but i need it to be always open, as there will be no button to open it.
2. On small screen it seems to be ok.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mFCmCJb

Comment: Got you, check the codesanbox again, I updated it. You can achieve that modifying the breakpoints on clipped properties on the `v-navigation-drawer` and  `v-app-bar`. You also need to use the `permanent` prop on the navigation drawer and activate it only on `smAndUp`.  https://imgur.com/a/DmYuwUh

Comment: Btw, if you want the navigation drawer to use all the space on the side, like this https://imgur.com/a/h7jtVmf, just remove the clipped props on `v-navigation-drawer` and `v-app-bar`.

Answer (score 1):

@cmfc31's solution is great, but unfortunately it doesn't work with Vuetify 3 anymore.

Here's how you can have your nav drawer open by default on large screens with Vuetify 3:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useDisplay } from 'vuetify'

const { mobile } = useDisplay()

const navDrawerIsOpen = ref(!mobile.value)
</script>

<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="navDrawerIsOpen"
  >
    <!-- nav drawer contents here -->
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

For opening/closing the nav drawer mobile screens, you can use the usual open/close button in an app bar or any other way you like to toggle the value of `navDrawerIsOpen` between `true` and `false`.

You can also de-structure breakpoints from `useDisplay()` as we know them from Vuetify 2 (e.g. `smAndUp`) but I find the use of `mobile.value` the most elegant way to solve this specific problem.

You will find more about breakpoints in Vuetify 3 here: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/display-and-platform/